# Сравнить два списка не обращая внимание на регистр

Tags: python

```
current_users = ['Arin', 'Kler', 'Ira', 'Kir', 'Mac']
new_users = ['Karl', 'Arin', 'IRA', 'Nar', 'Irk']
for name in current_users: 
    if name in new_users:
        print("имя занято")
    else:
        print("имя свободно")
```

Нужно дополнить, чтобы не обращал внимание на регистр, иначе имя Ira выдаёт как свободное. Видимо, где-то нужно присобачить `.lower()` или `.upper()`
Но не могу понять где, к списку же нельзя

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно поступить так:

```
In [45]: def foo(Name):
    ...:     current_users = ['Arin', 'Kler', 'Ira', 'Kir', 'Mac']
    ...:     new_users = ['Karl', 'Arin', 'IRA', 'Nar', 'Irk']
    ...:     if Name.lower() in set(map(str.lower, current_users)) - set(map(str.lower, new_users)):
    ...:         return True
    ...:     return False
    ...:
```

Результат:

```
In [46]: foo('Arin')
Out[46]: False

In [47]: foo('Kler')
Out[47]: True
```

Но как сказал @retorta, сравнивание может работать по разному.

---

Вот более понятный для вас пример:

```
In [54]: current_users = ['Arin', 'Kler', 'Ira', 'Kir', 'Mac']
    ...: new_users = ['Karl', 'Arin', 'IRA', 'Nar', 'Irk']
    ...: for i in current_users:
    ...:     if i.lower() in map(str.lower, new_users):
    ...:         print('Имя {0} занято'.format(i))
    ...:     else:
    ...:         print('Имя {0} свободно'.format(i))
    ...:
```

Результат:

```
Имя Arin занято
Имя Kler свободно
Имя Ira занято
Имя Kir свободно
Имя Mac свободно
```

Comment: На это мои знания тоже не распространяются, но до меня дошло, что нужно список привести к строковому типу. Спасибо в любом случае

Comment: @user254225 это разница множеств, в данном случаи мы выбираем все имена что входят в `current_users` но не входят в `new_users`, а функция `map()` применяет к каждому элементу списка функцию `lower()`

Comment: @user254225 обновил ответ, добавил более понятный пример.

Answer (score 5):

Вариант основанный на `.lower()` и `.upper()` может не работать.
Известный пример, что `.upper().lower()` не обязательно тождественное отображение:

```
"ß".upper().lower() # ss
```

Вместо этого можно использовать следующий [вариант](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29247821/8071517), который чуть более сложный, но заведомо работает:

```
import unicodedata 

def normalize_caseless(text):
    return unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", text.casefold()) 

def caseless_equal(left, right):
    return normalize_caseless(left) == normalize_caseless(right)

def incase(string, it):
    for i in it:
        if caseless_equal(string, i):
            return True
    return False

print(incase('ira',['Arin', 'Kler', 'Ira', 'Kir', 'Mac'])) # True
```

Comment: А можно увидеть не всегда работающий вариант? Просто только осваиваю питон, там было такое задание и завис, а того, что ты написал, там пока что не было

Comment: Ну в ответе и есть пример. Если попытаться, например, привести к верхенму регисту строки (`'abẞ'` и `'abß'`), то обычное их сравнение выдаст неправильный результат `print('abẞ'.upper() == 'abß'.upper()) # False`

Comment: Я бы сказал, что `.upper().lower()` почти всегда НЕ тождественное преобразование)) `'A'.upper().lower() != 'A'`